SSMS Key Not Valid, Where Are the Registered Servers Stored?
I've been getting the "Key not valid for use in specified state" message in both SSMS versions 19 and 20. My understanding is that this error comes from an encrypted password stored as part of a registered server.

I've deleted all registered servers in the app.
I've looked for the regsrvr.xml file in appdata/roaming/microsoft/microsoft sql server/* like all the search results suggested and haven't been able to find it.
I've done a search on my C drive for 'regsrvr' without any luck.
I've uninstalled, deleted all the program files, restarted, and reinstalled SSMS v20.1.
I've tried to reset my settings with the import/export tool.

I'm still getting five of these error messages every time I launch SSMS.
Is there another place registered servers are stored?

This answer from the linked duplicate explicitly denotes where the file is.

I stopped scrolling the list of directories after 'microsoft sql server'. I found the registered servers under a new path when I sorted by date modified.
AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio*
I just deleted the entire folder since it was a fresh install. No more errors.
